# BeanDefinitionParsingException when trying to use JPA with Kotlin and Spring boot

Tags: spring, maven, jpa, spring-boot, kotlin

I get this exception when i try to use springboot + JPA + kotlin + maven

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: 
Configuration problem: @Bean method 'init' must not be private or final; 
change the method's modifiers to continue
Offending resource: com.wirecard.kotlin.jpa.Application
at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.FailFastProblemReporter.error(FailFastProblemReporter.java:70)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.BeanMethod.validate(BeanMethod.java:50)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClass.validate(ConfigurationClass.java:219)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.validate(ConfigurationClassParser.java:528)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:307)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:239)
at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:254)
at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:94)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:606)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:462)
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:686)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:957)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:946)
at com.wirecard.kotlin.jpa.ApplicationKt.main(Application.kt:50)
```

I followed the example in this link but it is built using Gradle

> [Springboot application for kotlin and JPA](https://github.com/sdeleuze/spring-boot-kotlin-demo)

The code consists of 3 classes

### Class Customer

```
import javax.persistence.Entity
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue
import javax.persistence.GenerationType
import javax.persistence.Id

@Entity
class Customer(
    val firstName: String,
    val lastName: String,
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    val id: Long = -1) {

    override fun toString(): String {
    return "Customer(id=$id, firstName='$firstName', lastName='$lastName')"
    }
}
```

### Class CustomerController

```
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController

@RestController
class CustomerController(val repository:CustomerRepository) {

    @GetMapping("/")
    fun findAll() = repository.findAll()

    @GetMapping("/{lastName}")
    fun findByLastName(@PathVariable lastName:String)
            = repository.findByLastName(lastName)
}
```

### Interface CustomerRepository

```
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository

interface CustomerRepository : CrudRepository<Customer, Long> {

    fun findByLastName(lastName: String): Iterable<Customer>
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the log it looks like it's actually the 4th class, `Application`, that you're having a problem with. It says that the `init` method in that class shouldn't be `private` or `final`, your problem here would be the latter - functions and classes in Kotlin are `final` by default.

You can make the method non-final by marking it with the `open` keyword.

```
@Bean
open fun init(repository: CustomerRepository) = CommandLineRunner { ... }
```

You'll also have to mark your `Application` class with the `open` keyword.

```
@SpringBootApplication
open class Application { ... }
```

---

The reason these `open` keywords are not in the example is because it uses the [`kotlin-spring`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/compiler-plugins.html#kotlin-spring-compiler-plugin) plugin ([see in the build script](https://github.com/sdeleuze/spring-boot-kotlin-demo/blob/master/build.gradle.kts#L20)), which opens up the classes and functions that Spring requires to be non-final.

You should be able to use the `kotlin-spring` plugin with Maven as well, if you don't want to manually make your classes `open`. The instructions for doing so are right above the Gradle instructions, at the end of the chapter about the [`all-open`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/compiler-plugins.html#how-to-use-all-open-plugin) plugin. You just have to include the code that's there, and replace `<plugin>all-open</plugin>` with `<plugin>spring</plugin>`, as the comment there describes.